# How to implement a system to embed objects?

Tags: php, javascript, embed

What is the best way to implement an embedding scheme for the site.

Vimeo used to use `<object>` for embedding and now they switched to `<iframe>`. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both and which one in the industry considered to be a better way?

**EDIT**

I saw that the PHP tag was removed. I use PHP for development, so I welcome suggestions how to implement embedding using PHP and JS.

Comment: `iframe` is commonly used to embed items into areas that do not allow script or object embeds (like facebook). If you examine the `iframe`'s output, I'll be the embed is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason that video sites switch to using iframes now are in such cases of embedding. The page they link to (in the iframe src) is a simple page to test if the browser supports HTML5, and if so then use the native HTML5 video. If not, they default back to using flash. This is effective for mobile phones that don't support flash.

Disadvantages: Not sure.